# Automatically answer command input from .py script

Tags: command-line, batch, python

I am running a python script that asks for some input before continuing. I run the script from a batch file. **Is there a way to write the batch file to automatically plug in the user input? eg. "3"**

Here's what my python script looks like.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    algo = int(input("Which algorithm are you running?: "))
    program = Program(r"C:\Users\Administrator\algo_{}.cfg".format(algo), algo)
    calculation = program.calculate_algo()
```

Here's what my current batch file looks like.

```
call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
python Algo_demo.py
cmd/k
```

I understand that in the python file **"Algo_demo.py"** the first line requests the user input. Is there a way to 'queue' up an integer to plug in automatically, even though it is technically still in the same batch file command line?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want to get rid of the `input` part you can just replace everything in that line after  `algo =` with whatever integer you want, for example `algo = 1`, but you have not provided enough code that would explain what numbers are valid, so the example may be invalid.

Comment: Try: echo 3 | python Algo_demo.py or python Algo_demo.py 3

Comment: I don't want to hard code the '3' into my python script because I'm running the same script with different algos at the same time. I'll try your suggestions Ricardo!

Comment: @RicardoBohner That worked wonderfully! adding "echo 3 | " before the 2nd line worked! Can you put the answer in so you get credit?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo 3 | python Algo_demo.py
```

or

```
echo %var% | python Algo_demo.py
```

where `%var%` is a variable you previously defined....